# How to reorder a file depending on the scores

Tags: java, file-writing

I want to read in a file and reorder the file's list so that the highest score is at the top.

```
public static void showWinners()
    {
        //declaring variables and assigning values
        String [][] szWinnersList;
        String[] szLineArray = new String[1];
        int i,j;

        try
        {
            //call the readInFile procedure
            readInFile();
            
            //call writeWinner procedure
            writeWinner();

            //create String array to store new record in
            szWinnersList = new String [iLength][2];

            //for loop reads each row in
            for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            {
                //reads in the current line
                //assign the file to the array
                szLineArray = infile.nextLine().trim().split(",");

                //for loop assigns values to the 2D array
                for (j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
                {
                    //trims off all spaces
                    szWinnersList[i][j] = szLineArray[j];
                }//end for j
            }//end for i
            
            //call reorderWinners procedure
            reorderWinners(szWinnersList);

            //print out winners table
            winnersTable(szWinnersList, i);
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error1 - Writing to File: " + e);
        }//end catch
        {
            //finally runs regardless of wheter the try has worked
            //the aim of a finally is to tidy up any loose ends
            //if the contents within read is not equal to nothing i.e. it was possible to open and read
            //close the file (try) if the file was not loaded catch the exception IOException
            try
            {
                bw.close();
            }//end try when BufferedWriter is closed
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error - Closing BufferWriter: " + e);
            }//end catch

            try
            {
                file.close();
            }//end try when FileWriter is closed
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error - closing FileWriter: " + e);
            }//end catch
        }//end try catch finally
    }//end procedure
    
    
    // ======================================================================
    public static void writeWinner()
    {
        //declaring variables and assigning values
        String szWriteWinner;
        
        //string build the szWriteWinner
        szWriteWinner = szWinner[0][0] + "," + szWinner[0][1] + ("\n");

        try
        {
            //write winner in the csv file
            bw.write(szWriteWinner);
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error2 - Writing to File: " + e);
        }//end catch
    }//end writeWinner procedure
    

    // ======================================================================
    public static void readInFile()
    {
        try
        {
            infile = new Scanner (new File("DiceGameWinners.csv"));

            //construct a FileWriter object
            //the default argument is false so the write would overwrite the contents of the file each time
            file = new FileWriter("DiceGameWinners.csv", true);

            //needed for methods
            bw = new BufferedWriter(file);

            while (infile.hasNext())
            {
                szInLine = infile.nextLine();
                iLength++;
            }//end while

            infile.close();
            infile = null;

            //create the readers to read in the file DiceGameWinners.csv
            infile = new Scanner (new File("DiceGameWinners.csv"));
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error3 - Writing to File: " + e);
        }//end catch
    }//end procedure


    // ======================================================================
    public static void reorderWinners(String[][] szWinnersList) 
    {
        String szLine = "";
        int n = szWinnersList.length;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        {
            int j = i - 1;
            int iKey = Integer.parseInt(szWinnersList[i][1]);
            String szKey = szWinnersList[i][0];

            // insertion sort
            while (j >= 0 && Integer.parseInt(szWinnersList[j][1]) > iKey) 
            {
                szWinnersList[j + 1][0] = szWinnersList[j][0];
                szWinnersList[j + 1][1] = szWinnersList[j][1];
                j--;
            }//end while when insertion sort is finished

            //insert the key element into its correct position
            szWinnersList[j + 1][0] = szKey;
            szWinnersList[j + 1][1] = String.valueOf(iKey);
        }//end for loop when szWinnersList is reordered

        try 
        {
            //write each entry in the szWinnersList array to the file
            for (i = 0; i < szWinnersList.length; i++) 
            {
                szLine = szWinnersList[i][0] + "," + szWinnersList[i][1] + "\n";
                bw.write(szLine);
            }// end for when each entry has been entered into the file

            bw.close();
            file.close();
        }//end try
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error4 - Writing to File: " + e);
        }// end catch
}// end reorderWinners procedure
```

I tried to read in the file and then write the winner of the game so if the user's winning score is top 5, it will update the file so the next time the top 5 winning scores is shown, the user's score is there. I keep getting errors like: "can't parse null string" and "Index 1 out of bounds for length 1". What should I do and are there any improvements overall?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the _DiceGameWinners.csv_ contents?  It is one line of scores, comma-separated, or multiple lines each with a score?

Comment: m6rbles,68
MZ_BiC_19,66
JackJohnS,60
SillyB0bs,59
S3R3,48
MarkAbdu11ah,44
REROCKERS,41
CART_CReeping,37
BlackMONSTER,33
GeneralMark,31
REROCKERS,76
m6rbles,56
REROCKERS,66
REROCKERS,68
REROCKERS,42
m6rbles,42
m6rbles,48
m6rbles,34
REROCKERS,42
m6rbles,50

comma-separated

Answer (score -1):

There are a few approaches you can take here.

You can, optionally, contain the data for each player.

A basic approach would be just use a parallel array.
So, one will contain the scores, and the other the names.

As you sort the *scores* array, also adjust the *names* array.

Here is how to capture each value within a separate array—for use with your *reorderWinners* method.
As a note, I had to fix the provided data, there was a leading *"m6rbles"*, and a trailing *"50"*.

```java
File file = new File("DiceGameWinners.csv");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
String[] strings = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
int[] scores = new int[strings.length];
String[] names = new String[strings.length];
int index = 0;
String[] values;
for (String string : strings) {
    values = string.split(" ");
    scores[index] = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
    names[index] = values[1];
    index++;
}
```

Another approach would be to utilize the *[Arrays#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))* method on the *split* return value.
Which, in this case, begins with a number.
You can then use the *[Collections#reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))* method, to reverse the array.

```java
File file = new File("files/DiceGameWinners.csv");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
String[] players = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
Arrays.sort(players);
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(players));
```

Output

```
76 m6rbles
68 REROCKERS
68 MZ_BiC_19
66 REROCKERS
66 JackJohnS
60 SillyB0bs
59 S3R3
56 REROCKERS
50 m6rbles
48 m6rbles
48 MarkAbdu11ah
44 REROCKERS
42 m6rbles
42 m6rbles
42 m6rbles
41 CART_CReeping
37 BlackMONSTER
34 REROCKERS
33 GeneralMark
31 REROCKERS
```

Comment: Thanks, so I just replace my code with your fixed one?

Comment: Essentially.  You'll have some re-factoring, of course.  I'm unable to adapt your code because it doesn't cover all the values.  I imagined providing an example would be more logical than re-factoring code I wouldn't be able to run.

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit confused.. If you want to see the code then https://ideone.com/bY6LfH

Comment: So, you can create a new class field, or fields, to hold the data.  And, then, since they are sorted by score, you would simply need to save the array to the file.  _String.join(",", scores)_.

Comment: As I'm new to coding, I don't exactly know what you mean, could you show me please?